# Changing CSS properties of a Haml table from Rails view

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to change the table header background color from a view, so that when I click on the table header URL, its background color changes.

I have this resumed view in Haml:

```
%table#movies
  %thead
   %tr
    %th= link_to "Movie Title", movie_path, :id => "title_header" -#this is the table header
```

And this the CSS style I want to apply to the table header once “Movie Title” gets clicked on:

```css
table#movies th {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I don’t know how to bind a click with the table header background color.
This problem was taken from a online course it's a homework, and we can't use javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution I've found in some Git repository

A helper method is requerid for checking if the %th is the class I need to apply the style

```
def helper_class(field)
 if(params[:sort].to_s == field)
   return 'hilite'
 else
   return nil
 end
end
```

Previous method is called in the view just in the %th tag

```
%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:id => 'title_header', :class => helper_class('title') }= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort=>'title', :ratings =>params[:ratings]), :id => 'title_header'
      %th Rating
      %th{:id => 'release_date_header', :class => helper_class('release') }= link_to "Release Date", movies_path(:sort=>'release',:ratings =>params[:ratings]), :id => 'release_date_header'
      %th More Info
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td= movie.title 
        %td= movie.rating
        %td= movie.release_date
        %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

With this code the table header which have as class `:class => hilite` will be changed to the this style that I put on the question.

Thanks to you all for helping me with this, I am new in web development.

Comment: Where did you add the helper_class? When I try this I get noMethodError"

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript:

```coffeescript
$('#title_header').click( ()->
  $(this).toggleClass('active')
)
```

CSS:

```css
#title_header.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Make sure you have only one `#title_header` – otherwise, change it to a class.

**Update**
If you don't want to use javascript like you say in your comment:

```
%table#movies
  %thead
   %tr
    %th= link_to "Movie Title", movie_path, :id => "title_header", onclick: "$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow')"
```

Comment: Thanks man but I am not working with coffeescript it's helm in rails.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Haml is just a short way of writing HTML. And HTML doesn’t support behavior on user clicks (except for Submit buttons). You need JavaScript (or CoffeeScript, a short way of writing JavaScript) to support that.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Ok, thanks for make me undertand that, I took this (and other problems) from a online course and one note was do not use javascript.

Comment: If CSS had parent selectors, then we could have a pure non-js solution :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:visited`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) pseudo selector.

```
#movies th a:visited {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

The styles above are applied for visited links. However, note that the styles are applied on `a`, not `th`.

Answer (score 0):

```
%th{:class => ("hilite" if params[:id]== "title_header")}= link_to 'Movie Title', movies_path(id: 'title_header')
```

Comment: some explanation would be helpful